# PM2 - SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server, coffeescript, pm2

I'm currently installing a NodeJS service on an Ubuntu server. The application is written in coffeescript and runs fine on it's own. This is how I setup the project:

```
cd ~/test-project
nvm use v4.9.1
npm install
pm2 start index.js
```

However when I try to start it using pm2 i get the error below:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/needle/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:132
    let val = process.env[key];
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/needle/node_modules/debug/src/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

And after doing some testing it seems that this error occurs no matter what script I start with pm2 so there must be something that isn't configured correctly..

I don't know if it matters but the script I am trying to run needs node v4.9.1 so I am using NVM to use that version, it seems to me that it is trying to run pm2 with that same node version somehow?

Any input is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for way too long!!

Comment: I have the same problem and I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on node version 4.x,

Downgraded the pm2 and it worked.

```
npm uninstall -g pm2
npm install -g pm2@3.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';
```

Add above line of code to first line of the script file. `let` is used when you want a variable to be scoped to a block which is supported in strict mode in `node v4`.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for more details.

Comment: But where would I add this? I've even tried to start a script that only has a console.log in it, shouldn't that work anyway?

Comment: This should be added at first line. I don't think for `console.log` this would be the error, can you share error logs for that case.

Comment: Wrote an answer below!

Answer (score 0):

@Vishnu Sing this is the complete output. The `index.js` file looks like this:

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-5:~/test-project$ nano index.js 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-5:~/test-project$ node -v
v10.15.3
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-5:~/test-project$ sudo pm2 start index.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/needle/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:132
    let val = process.env[key];
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/needle/node_modules/debug/src/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-5:~/test-project$
```

Comment: I think your code is not getting updated. Why don't you try it directly with `node` by simply running `node index.js` if it works well it means you have problem in pm2 configurations.

Comment: Tried that as well but still get the same error. So yeah there is something wrong in the pm2 configurations. I have just installed it though and followed the Quick start on their website.

Comment: Verify that the code is saved or not by running: `cat index.js`. I think if running `node index.js` is also giving same error means that the code is not saved yet or you are in wrong directory.

Comment: Yeah it works, I meant that pm2 still doesn't work even though `node index.js` works fine.

Comment: I think you should remove all older processes then only start this one. Try running `pm2 ls` to see all processes currently running. Stop stale processes by `pm2 delete <app-name>` then only start this process. See documentation: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/process-management/#process-management