# Running app with pm2 start server.js causes SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, vps, pm2

On my VPS, if I run an app using:

> node server.js

It runs perfectly fine:
[image]

But, when I tried running it using pm2:

> pm2 start server.js

I get this error:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:136
>
> let val = process.env[key];
>
> ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)
> not yet supported outside strict mode
>
> at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>
> ```
> at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>
> at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>
> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/debug/src/index.js:9:19)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
> ```

The solution mentioned in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842552/pm2-syntaxerror-block-scoped-declarations-not-yet-supported-outside-strict-mo) didn't change anything:

> I had the same issue on node version 4.x,
>
> Downgraded the pm2 and it worked.
>
> npm uninstall -g pm2 npm install -g pm2@3.0.4

---

**NOTE 1:**
When I run:

```
node -v
```

I get:

> v15.8.0

And when I run:

```
nodejs -v
```

I get:

> v4.2.6

But, when I run:

> which node

I get this:

> /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v15.8.0/bin/node

I even updated to both these versions using ***nvm***, and it still didn't work:
[image]

[image]

---

**NOTE 2:**
I installed pm2 using this command:

```
sudo npm i -g pm2
```

But, when I list globally installed node modules using this command:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

This is what I see:

[image]

As you see pm2 is not there.

I have tried the same thing on my personal PC and I can see pm2 is there:
[image]
And running the app with pm2 actually worked.

---

> NOTE 3:
> I have no idea why but running it with pm2 suddenly worked:
> [image]

### With node version 15.8.0

**NOTE 4:**

It stopped working so I tried this:

I added the path to the specific version of node that I am using to the `PATH` env variable:

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v15.8.0/bin"

And then reinstalled pm2:

```
npm i -g pm2
```

And then checked the globally installed npm modules for that specific node version:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

And I found pm2 installed:
[image]

I am not sure this is the correct way to solve this but it  works.

---

Thoughts?